# return 2 values javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to return two values in GAS like this:
Html

```
<script>
  function phoneSearch() {
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).phoneSearch(phone);
  }
  function onSuccess(name, email) {
    document.getElementById('nameDiv').innerHTML = "<div>" + name + "</div>";
    document.getElementById('emailDiv').innerHTML = "<div>" + email+ "</div>";
  } 
</script>
```

Server JS

```js
function phoneSearch(phone){
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheetNameHere");
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i][4] == phone) {
        var name = inputData[i][3];
        var email = inputData[i][5];
        return name;
        return email;
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {
    alert(e)
  }
}
```

Only the first value (name) returns. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't return twice from a function. You've to return an object or array containing the values you need.

Comment: Would you advice a sample code please. I tried many with no luck so far. Thanks for your time

Comment: @Mahmoud, Maybe, with the help of [this](https://ntgard.medium.com/tuples-in-javascript-cd33321e5277) link, you can answer your own question and harvest all the Stack Overflow karma that that entails. 

Comment: I'm not familiar with GAS, but it looks like you never even use the return value of `phoneSearch` ..?

Comment: @Teemu: `onSuccess`

Comment: @BigSmoke, I will of course. thanks for sharing

Comment: @Teemu, I will use the returned two values to update another form inputs in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only return 1 value from your function at a time, but you can easily wrap that in an object:

```
<script>
  function phoneSearch() {
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).phoneSearch(phone);
  }
  function onSuccess(result) {
  //                  ^ phoneSearch now returns -one- object, containing `name` and `email`.
    document.getElementById('nameDiv').innerHTML = "<div>" + result.name + "</div>";
    document.getElementById('emailDiv').innerHTML = "<div>" + result.email+ "</div>";
  } 
</script>
```

JS

```
function phoneSearch(phone){
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheetNameHere");
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i][4] == phone) {
        var name = inputData[i][3];
        var email = inputData[i][5];
        // Return both values at once. 
        return { name, email };
        // (This is shorthand for: `return { name: name, email: email };`)
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {
    alert(e)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use more one 'return' at the same level, you should return object containing your two values.

```js
return {
   phone: phone,
   email: email
}
```